# ruby on rails if else logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I shorten my if else statement below.

Right now the only difference in the 2 statments is the first line.
accordion-body
and
accordion-body.collapse.

```
- if @office.to_i == office.id
        .accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}"}
          .accordion-inner 
            - office.positions.each_with_index do |position, index|
              #measures-accordion.accordion
                .accordion-group
                  .accordion-heading
                    .row-fluid
                      .span2{class: "offices-#{position.status}"}= position.status
                      .span1= position.results.first.value
                      .span2= position.results.first.value_date_time.blank? ? '' : Date.parse(position.results.first.value_date_time)
                      .span5= position.name
      - else
        .accordion-body.collapse{id: "collapse-#{index}"}
          .accordion-inner 
            - office.positions.each_with_index do |position, index|
              #measures-accordion.accordion
                .accordion-group
                  .accordion-heading
                    .row-fluid
                      .span2{class: "offices-#{position.status}"}= position.status
                      .span1= position.results.first.value
                      .span2= position.results.first.value_date_time.blank? ? '' : Date.parse(position.results.first.value_date_time)
                      .span5= position.name
```

The above code works . But if i shorten it to below, my logic does not work

```
    - if @office.to_i == office.id
      .accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}"}
    - else
      .accordion-body.collapse{id: "collapse-#{index}"}
      .accordion-inner 
        - office.positions.each_with_index do |position, index|
          #measures-accordion.accordion
            .accordion-group
              .accordion-heading
                .row-fluid
                  .span2{class: "offices-#{position.status}"}= position.status
                  .span1= position.results.first.value
                  .span2= position.results.first.value_date_time.blank? ? '' : Date.parse(position.results.first.value_date_time)
                  .span5= position.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend moving the repeated code into a partial, but if you want to do it without that, try:

```
    .accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}", class: (@office.to_i == office.id) ? "" : "collapse" }
      .accordion-inner 
        - office.positions.each_with_index do |position, index|
          #measures-accordion.accordion
            .accordion-group
              .accordion-heading
                .row-fluid
                  .span2{class: "offices-#{position.status}"}= position.status
                  .span1= position.results.first.value
                  .span2= position.results.first.value_date_time.blank? ? '' : Date.parse(position.results.first.value_date_time)
                  .span5= position.name
```

Comment: great answer.it worked. But it would be more helpful if you could explain whats goin on in that line of code

Comment: When you do `.accordion-body.collapse` you're actually just making a `div` with CSS classes `accordion-body` and `collapse`. This is a HAML short hand. However, you can pass in the CSS classes as an option. In this case, @Dogbert's code makes a `div` with the `accordion-body` CSS class using the HAML short hand, but then uses the ability to pass in options to either pass it in an additional class of `collapse`, or none at all.